# Debugger always paused in ntdll.Kifastsystemcallret

Tags: x64dbg

I am using x32dbg to debug a program. I want to find the line which corresponds to a pop up message in my program to put a Break point.
But everytime that I set "Pause" after the pop up window's opening the program stops in Kifastsystemcallret in ntdll module.
I succeed one time to set a Break point and to work it fine, but I can't do it anymore...
I don't understand...
Thanks for advance for answering and sorry for my bad english and capacities in debugging...

---

[image]Thanks for your answer... I've uploaded two photos... The first shows the call stacks ; the second the KiFastSystemCallRet... I don't know where down the line I will return.
I've tried to type all the expression adresses without any success...

[image]

Comment: If you are trying to backtrace where the pop up message was called, you can try to set a breakpoint in MessageBoxA if it uses that WinAPI and check the call stack.

Answer (score 1):

when any app is performing a system call it is normal to pause on KiFastSystemCallRet  ( windbg callstack for 4 threads when application is paused windbg uses a seperate thread to breakin so the current thread is paused at DoDebugBreak

```
0:003> ~*k2

   0  Id: da4.a8c Suspend: 1 Teb: 7ffdf000 Unfrozen
ChildEBP RetAddr
0019ead4 75c1cde0 ntdll!KiFastSystemCallRet
0019ead8 75c1ce13 USER32!NtUserGetMessage+0xc

   1  Id: da4.a24 Suspend: 1 Teb: 7ffde000 Unfrozen
ChildEBP RetAddr
00b6fce8 77456a44 ntdll!KiFastSystemCallRet
00b6fcec 755e6a36 ntdll!NtWaitForMultipleObjects+0xc

   2  Id: da4.ce8 Suspend: 1 Teb: 7ffdd000 Unfrozen
ChildEBP RetAddr
029ffec0 77456a44 ntdll!KiFastSystemCallRet
029ffec4 73e5a41c ntdll!NtWaitForMultipleObjects+0xc

#  3  Id: da4.d8c Suspend: 1 Teb: 7ffdc000 Unfrozen
ChildEBP RetAddr
02b9f7f8 774af20f ntdll!DbgBreakPoint
02b9f828 75a1ed6c ntdll!DbgUiRemoteBreakin+0x3c
0:003>
```

a system call is a call which transitions from user mode to kernel mode

using sysenter instruction normally

when you issue a pause (f12 , esc) and when paused in that function take a look at call stack to see where down the line you will return

(you can type printstack in x64dbg commandline also to dump the call stack to log window)

```
17 call stack frames (EIP = 774570F4 , ESP = 000AE8EC , EBP = 000AE8FC ):
000AE900 ntdll._KiFastSystemCallRet@0
000AE910 uxtheme.74371A62
000AE920 uxtheme.74371A2F
000AE970 uxtheme.74371D38
000AE98C uxtheme.74371F20
000AE9D4 user32._GetRealWindowOwner@4+78
000AEE60 calc.00F51F4F
000AEE8C user32._InternalCallWinProc@20+23
000AEF04 user32._UserCallWinProcCheckWow@32+B3
000AEF60 user32._DispatchClientMessage@20+4B
000AEF88 user32.___fnDWORD@4+24
000AEFD4 ntdll._KiUserCallbackDispatcher@12+2E
000AFD50 calc.00F51CBC
000AFDE0 calc.00F6219A
000AFDEC kernel32.75A1ED6C
000AFE2C ntdll.___RtlUserThreadStart@8+27
000AFE44 ntdll.__RtlUserThreadStart@8+1B
```